# LMS with drupal or Joomla?

Tags: drupal, joomla

I will create a LMS site. But I don't know Is it possible in drupal? or in Joomla?
I want only these system core, And I don't need to a portal (I need to some page with my special theme, for admin, teachers and students and I don't need to these CMS pages).

Can I do my idea with Drupal? or with Joomla? Or I must start a new project from base??

(Sorry for my bad English)

Thanks ...

Comment: Maybe it's just me but I don't know what LMS is.

Comment: Wikipedia:: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Learning_management_system

Answer (score 3):

What do you need from the LMS and what CMS features do you need?  Drupal or Joomla may be a stretch if you need full SCORM functionality and/or sophisticated LMS features.  [Moodle](http://moodle.org) may be a better fit in that case.

Comment: I need a page, the admin and teachers can log into it. And another page for students, students can log into it and see their state.

Comment: I dabbled in Drupal LMS a few months ago, and there are:

http://groups.drupal.org/lms-learning-management-system

and

http://groups.drupal.org/node/63463

both have valuable info. Short short version, and that is why this is a comment: integrate Moodle.

Answer (score 2):

It's very possible in either Drupal or Joomla. I personally like Drupal more than Joomla, and would encourage you to look in that direction. There is an actual tool called JoomlaLMS, which would probably give you a better out of the box solution, but you will have to shell out quite a bit of cash.

If you're willing to spend quite a bit of time building your own system in Drupal, you could have a very good free solution. You could also end up with a huge mess if you don't know your way around Drupal.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with Joomla.  The reason is that Joomla is a much bigger project with many more people involved, so developers build many more addons, as Jimmy said.  I was able to put together an impressive website, www.shattergames.com with a very limited amount of work, just because so much has been done with Joomla.  That said, why not just use Moodle?